# Set content-type of topic with periods in Spring Cloud Stream

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I have a spring cloud stream app (Finchley.SR1) that has topics that have periods in the name. In the application.properties I want to set the content-type of the different topics, but because the topics have periods in them it's not working as expected.

My application.properties looks like this:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.topic1.with.periods.content-type=application/topic1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.topic2.with.periods.content-type=application/topic2
spring.cloud.stream.default.content-type=application/other
```

All of my messages are coming in with the content type set as `application/other` instead of having the correct content type header set. I have also tried using `contentType` instead of `content-type`, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need periods there?

You can name the binding with a simple name and set the `destination` to the dotted name.

```
@Output("foo")
MessageChannel foo();
```

Then

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.foo.destination=topic1.with.periods
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.foo.content-type=application/topic1
```

Comment: Somehow I missed this in the documentation. Thanks!